# Eclipse update site

Tags: java, eclipse-wtp

I am trying to install eclipse WTP and am getting dependency issues.

In order to install the missing dependencies I am trying to load them from the Galileo update site: `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo`  However, when I try to open this update site, no items show up.  I tried messing around with the options (group items by category, show only latest versions...) but no luck.  Any ideas why I can't see the software under this update site?  I'm pretty sure I need to install some dependencies from here (emf..) in order to get WTP working.

Thanks

Comment: on what kind of system do you have your eclipse running ? On my linux, the items do not appear. but if you pass the mouse over the empty box, you may see in the comments the description of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your firewall is blocking Eclipse, preventing Eclipse from getting the list of plugins from the update site.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting with Eclipse 3.5.x?

If WTP is your destination, it might just be easier to start with a preassembled Galileo package from http://eclipse.org/downloads/ .  The "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" contains the entirety of WTP and its prerequisites.